# ONSEN UIでカメラロールのようなUI実装は可能ですか？

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

ONSEN UIでカメラロールのようなUI実装事例を探しています。
見つからなかったので、擬似的に以下のコードで実現しています。

```
            <ons-list-item class="item" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
                <ons-row>
                    <ons-col width="55px" ng-click="doSomething()" style="margin: 1px;">
                        <img id="picture" src="" width="55" height="55" />
                    </ons-col>
                    <ons-col width="55px" ng-click="doSomething()" style="margin: 1px;">
                        <img id="picture" src="" width="55" height="55" />
                    </ons-col>
                    <ons-col width="55px" ng-click="doSomething()" style="margin: 1px;">
                        <img id="picture" src="" width="55" height="55" />
                    </ons-col>
                    <ons-col width="55px" ng-click="doSomething()" style="margin: 1px;">
                        <img id="picture" src="" width="55" height="55" />
                    </ons-col>
                    <ons-col width="55px" ng-click="doSomething()" style="margin: 1px;">
                        <img id="picture" src="" width="55" height="55" />
                    </ons-col>
                </ons-row>
            </ons-list-item>
```

上記実装だとデバイス端末の解像度により左側の空白が目立つこと、または段下がりになって
表示してしまう等で調整が必要になります。

デバイス端末の解像度に依存しない上記UIを実現したいのですが、もし解決方法がございましたら
ご教授のほどお願いいたします。